# Thread-safety-Java

Tags: java

If I use a Collection which is not thread safe and I just do some get on (Add in a static bloc), and the elements which are put in, have thread safe methods, that's thread safe ?

Moreover, "static final" variables are they thread safe ?

In last, the example above are they equals ?

Example 1 :

```
public class Test {

     private static int cpt = 1;

     public synchronized void increment(){
          i++;
     }
}
```

Example 2 :

```
public class Test {

     private static Data cpt = new Data(1);

     public void increment(){
          cpt.inc();
     }
}

public class Data {

     private int compt;

     public Data(int cpt){
          compt = cpt;
     }

     public synchronized void inc(){
          compt++;               
     }
}
```

Example 3 :

```
public class Test {

     private static Data cpt = new Data(1);

     public void increment(){
          synchronized(cpt){
               cpt.inc();
          }
     }
}

public class Data {

     private int compt;

     public Data(int cpt){
          compt = cpt;
     }

     public void inc(){
          compt++;               
     }
}
```

Thanks you very much ! :)

Comment: Third example should be `synchronized(cpt)`, not `synchronized(Data)`, and I don't think you can set a field of type `Data` to `1`.

Comment: Yes sorry it was a mistake

Comment: 2nd and 3rd examples are roughly equivalent, but #2 is probably better since it guarantees synchronization outside of the `Test` class. 1st example is different because it synchronizes on the instance of `Test` instead of the instance of `Data`.

Comment: Imagine you are in a space ship, you want the air to be kept in on all sides, not just part of it.  Unless all the code is thread safe, its not thread safe.  Example 1 is not thread safe. Example 2 is, Example 3 might be.

Answer (score 0):

Static Final Variables are they thread safe?

> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. This can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or malicious code. final fields must be used correctly to provide a guarantee of immutability.
>
> Memory that can be shared between threads is called shared memory or heap memory. 
>   All instance fields, static fields, and array elements are stored in heap memory. In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to both fields and array elements. 
>   Local variables (§14.4), formal method parameters (§8.4.1), and exception handler parameters (§14.20) are never shared between threads and are unaffected by the memory model.

Above information came from here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

static fields could be thread safe and final fields could be depending on how it is used , so final static could be if used properly.

So final static or final is sort of the same thing in this case:

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
final int x;
int y; 
static FinalFieldExample f;

public FinalFieldExample() {
    x = 3; 
    y = 4; 
} 

static void writer() {
    f = new FinalFieldExample();
} 

static void reader() {
    if (f != null) {
        int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
        int j = f.y;  // could see 0
    } 
}
```

}

When it comes to threads, thread1 could see 0 for y or 4 because the constructor needs to be fully initialized for y to be 4 and thread1 could have got to y before the constructor did. But for x it is guaranteed.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that is does not make clear that ONLY a `static final` field that is IMMUTABLE is thread-safe. If the field is mutable in a non-thread-safe manner, it is not thread-safe. Also, next time please answer the question with analysis of the quote. The user may not have the knowledge to interpret the great quotation that you found.

Comment: Your statement that "static fields are thread safe" is incorrect. I could maintain a `List` object as a static field. This does not make that `List` thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

A `static final` object MAY be thread-safe IF it is *IMMUTABLE*. If it mutable and does not provide internal thread-safety, it is not thread safe.

As SJuan76 pointed out, example 1 is not thread-safe because you synchronized on the instance `this` by making the method an instance method. If the method were static it would be thread-safe. It is also considered poor design practice to synchronize on an instance that other code has access to and could also obtain a lock upon. By doing the default `synchronize` on an instance method, you lock on that instance. Since the caller has a reference to that instance, the caller could also get a synchronized lock on that instance. The same is true (even more so) by making the method static. Then the lock is acquired on the class object, any other code could then acquire a lock on the class, even without a specific instance.

Examples 2 & 3 are equivalently thread-safe as both synchronize on the `Data` instance that is held privately.